# excell grouping with some totals above and others below

Tags: excel, grouping, excel-2013

using excel 2013 and have a spreadsheet with many grouped rows.

Most of the grouped sections have a summary row at the bottom. This row contains the title for that section and a total for each of the columns.

so after creating the groups we go to Data--> click on the more button in the outline section and choose--> Summary Rows below detail

We have one section below  the others where we want to reverse it and have the summary row at the top. Is this possible? there doesn't seem to be a way to flip this for just one of the grouped sections. If we unselect "Summary rows below" it flips all of them and the + - sign no longer aligns with the summary row

if we don't un-check the "summary row below" box we have to leave the summary row for the reversed section out of the group and the + - sign appears next to the wrong row.

hopefully the attached image makes this make more sense

[image: picture of regular and reversed sections]

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution but for now moved the reversed sub groups above the reversed group summary row. Will have to see if the users are ok with it. Frustrating because this group is different from the others and would make sense if we could flip it. + the original data is automated so will have to manually flip.